# Scala - explicitly refer to parameter

Tags: scala

Given this awesome piece of totally pro Scala:

```
trait SomethingCool {
  def foo: Int => String
}

def makeSomethingCool(foo: Int => String = i => i.toString): SomethingCool = {
  new SomethingCool {
    override def foo = foo // method foo does nothing other than call itself recursively
  }
}
```

where I have a factory method for a trait that has a default implementation, how can I refer to the parameter name from within the `new SomethingCool { }`? It seems to get masked by the trait's function name.

Comment: Can't you just call the parameter something else?

Comment: I could respond with some sort of "why didn't I think of that" or even a "that's not an answer to the asked question regarding rules for variable name scope," but I won't. Instead, I'll say "thanks for the suggestion, I'll keep that in mind."

Comment: Oh, I was not trying to be rude or anything. Sorry if you thought that.

Comment: No worries! I'm just trying to understand the scoping rules Scala is using... It looks like if this were within the new trait instance then I could use something like `self =>` to set the name, but that trick doesn't seem to work with function declarations...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. But here is one workaround:

```
def makeSomethingCool(foo: Int => String = i => i.toString): SomethingCool = {
  val _foo = foo
  new SomethingCool {
    override def foo = _foo
  }
}
```